# button tag is not able to change font color on Iphone safari browser

Tags: html, css, browser, safari

this tag all the time retrieve on IOS safari browser black font color 
How I can change the font color to **white**?

```
 <button style='color:#fff !important ;'>Hello</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `appearance: none;` and / or `-webkit-appearance: none;` before your custom styling.

```
 <button style='-webkit-appearance: none; color:#fff !important ;'>Hello</button>
```

More info:

[MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance)

[CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/)